# Publish Intranet page is using another user's local publish path for the file being changed

Tags: publish

[Object reference not set to an instance of an object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQgSa.png)

When I publish an Intranet page update, I am getting an error that shows a user's local publish path for one of the files instead of using the web path. It isn't even MY local publish path..

When I publish to my local publish location, the file changed doesn't even publish/update locally.

When I run the project, it seems to work the first time (meaning no error), but when I perform that same task a subsequent time, this is when I get the Object reference error.

How can I fix the project/solution in order to hit the file/code I've changed?

We are using C#, ASP.NET core, Visual Studio 2019, on Windows 10.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, deleting upon build, restarting Visual Studio, restarting my system, get latest, undo checkout and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Was replacing just the one aspx file I made code changes to.

Must replace the entire project of files after Publish, not just the select files you (think) you've worked on. Changes are made to files behind and beyond the targeted file(s).

Publish locally, backup Prod files, copy local files to Prod server, Voila!